# Why do I shoot enemies in the left arm most of the time?

Tags: counter-strike

Here are my Counter Strike 1.6 `rankstats` for a certain period of play:

```
Kills : 971 (309 with hs)
Hits  : 3727
Shots : 17387
Acc.  : 21.43%

HITS      :
head      :  424 (11.95%)
chest     :  607 (17.10%)
stomach   :  406 (11.44%)
leftarm   : 1214 (34.21%)
rightarm  :  420 (11.83%)
leftleg   :  223 ( 6.28%)
rightleg  :  255 ( 7.19%)
```

Notice the very high percentage of shots aimed at the enemy's left arm. When shooting, I normally aim for the chest hoping for a headshot on the second or third fire but too may shots on left arm is unexplainable. Do I need to change my crosshair settings? Or should I aim a little towards right?

Comment: Maybe it's the positioning of the left arm when holding a gun? With a right handed trigger, and an underbarrel grip, the left arm would spend a large amount of time in front of the body.

Comment: Left arm hitbox includes the weapon.

Comment: I don't know about hitboxes in CS1.6 and what they include, but if you search for [CS1.6 images](https://www.google.ca/search?q=counter+strike+1.6&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X), for many weapons (primary exceptions being handguns/knives), the right arm is bent and off to the side to hold the trigger while the left arm crosses over in front of the chest. So, assuming you are firing at them while they are looking at you, their left arm would 'catch' a disproportionate amount of bullets compared to the right. (also you could be catching them unaware from their left side more than their right? :P)

Comment: http://3.firepic.org/3/images/2014-04/18/mibw0syirut2.jpg

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, you are not the only one who has this. It's very-very common.

Second, it happens because the left arm, which holds the front end of the gun, also covers a (huge) part of the chest and abdomen.

[image: Counter Strike models]

On this picture you can clearly see that when an opponent faces you(and it happens most of the time), his body is greatly protected by his left arm.

P.S. Switching weapon to the left hand won't help, other player models will still have weapons in their right hands.

**EDIT**

As [*Salman A*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/80832/salman-a) mentioned in his comment, I'll also add my profile picture:

[image: profile pic]

As you can see, my left arm is also covering my body(although it's a very bad idea to face an enemy like that) :-)

Comment: You can also add your profile picture to the answer!

Comment: @SalmanA there you go! ;-)